# Image taking too long to be printed on a web page - JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, css, image, onclick

I am new to JavaScript. My code is working fine when it comes to the logic of the algorithm. Just that I want an image to be printed on a web page, but it takes 3-4 minutes to show on the web page, whereas the control already moves out of that statement and executes the code further ahead. This is what I did:

```js
function displayCartoon(player, i, j){

        console.log("CONTROL HERE");
        let image = player == "Man" ? Boat : Goat;
        console.log("I AM HERE!!!!");
        
        //This ctx.drawImage is taking too long for it to print it in my web application 
        ctx.drawImage(image, j * SPACE_SIZE, i * SPACE_SIZE);
        console.log("CONTROL EXITED!");
    
}
```

I also tried to set a timer for the function and use `async` functions, but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: How big is your `image` in MB? It might be a connection issue - that means you are trying to load a huge image.

Comment: My Image size is 7 KB. It is very small I think. There is some performance issue with Canvas and ctx I think

Comment: Please provide an example of your code at either CodePen, JSFiddle, StackBlitz, etc. are share it here.